# Add related entities in many-to-many (EF 4.1)

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, many-to-many

I have two entities, `Search` and `SearchTerm` with a many-to-many relationship.  When I create a new `Search` and add a `List(Of SearchTerm)` along with it, everything works perfectly.  If I try to use an already existing `SearchTerm`, it crashes with:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.
>
> Inner Exception: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tblSearchesSearchTerms_tblSearchTerms". The conflict occurred in database "CASSAudits", table "dbo.tblSearchTerms", column 'SearchTermID'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Here's sample code:

```vb
Dim foundTerm As SearchTerm = DataSource.SearchTerms.FirstOrDefault(Function(term) term.FieldName = "fieldName")

DataSource.Searches.Add(New Search() With {
    .Terms = New List(Of SearchTerm) From { foundTerm }
}
DataSource.SaveChanges()
```

Here are the entities

```vb
Public Class SearchTerm
    Public Property SearchTermID As Integer

    Public Overridable Property Searches As ICollection(Of Search)

    Public Property FieldName As String
    Public Property ComparisonType As String
    Public Property Value As String
End Class

Public Class Search
    Public Property SearchID As Integer

    Public Overridable Property Terms As ICollection(Of SearchTerm)

    Public Property FromPage As String
    Public Property SearchDate As Date
    Public Property User As String
End Class
```

The many to many relationship is custom mapped in `OnModelCreating` like this:

```vb
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of Search) _
        .HasMany(Function(search) search.Terms) _
        .WithMany(Function(term) term.Searches) _
        .Map(Function(m) m.MapLeftKey("SearchTermID").MapRightKey("SearchID").ToTable("tblSearchesSearchTerms"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem with the help of [Express Profiler](http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/).  I mapped the left and right keys backwards so EF was trying to add the `SearchID` of the new search as the `SearchTermID` of the relationship.

```vb
modelBuilder.Entity(Of Search) _
    .HasMany(Function(search) search.Terms) _
    .WithMany(Function(term) term.Searches) _
    .Map(Function(m) m.MapLeftKey("SearchID").MapRightKey("SearchTermID").ToTable("tblSearchesSearchTerms"))
```